# How to create keyboard shortcuts for Copy & Paste Shape Attributes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, shortcuts, configuration

Something that is a little frustrating with `Copy Shape Attributes` and `Paste Shape Attributes` is that you can't assign a keyboard shortcut to it. When trying, I was unable to make it work. I have posted what I could get to work as an answer.

How can I create custom keyboard shortcuts for the `Copy Shape Attributes` & `Paste Shape Attributes` options in Adobe Photoshop?

<sub>To do it manually, you need to right click on a shape layer in the layers panel.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an action that assigns <kbd>F1+⌘+⇧</kbd> to <kbd>Copy Shape Attributes</kbd> and <kbd>F2+⌘+⇧</kbd> to <kbd>Paste Shape Attributes</kbd>. I hope this is useful for a few people who would like to quickly copy all of the shape attributes.

If you happen to have Keyboard Maestro I have also included the Macro Library if you want to save your fingers from having to stretch so far.

[Download from Dropbox: Photoshop Actions and Keyboard Maestro Macro Library](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u5cr2f5rffwtp8f/AAA2BdhCjnIIVajbuqmjqJH9a?dl=0)